# The Laplace transform of $\exp(t^2)$

Tags: improper-integrals, laplace-transform

A naive attempt to calculate the Laplace transform of the function $f(t)=e^{t^2}$ results in integrals of the form

$$\int_0^\infty e^{t^2-st}dt,$$ which obviously don't exist as the integrand grows too large. However, Wolfram Alpha/Mathematica gives [the following result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+transform+of+exp%28t%5E2%29)

$$F\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{s^2}{4}} $$
where $F$ is the [Dawson function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function).

Is this really the Laplace transform of $f(t)$? How can it even exist, and why is it complex?

Thank you!

Comment: Wolfram is known to be wrong sometimes. But formally I guess he does : $\int_{0}^\infty \exp(t^2-st)dt = \int_{-s/2}^\infty \exp(u^2)du.\exp(-s^2/4).= \int_0^{s/2} \exp(u^2)du.\exp(-s^2/4) + i \int_{i0}^{i\infty} \exp(-v^2) dv.\exp(-s^2/4) = F(s/2) - i\tfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.\exp(-s^2/4)$.

Comment: The integral you have written doesn't converge.  Dawson's function concerns integrals with finite limits.

Comment: $e^{t^2}$ is not of "exponential order". I would not trust that result.