# Exponential order in Laplace Transform:constructing a function such that it is of exponential order but its derivative is not.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, laplace-method

I don't understand how to construct such function.I know the definition of a function being of exponential order which states that:
 $f(t)$ is of exponential order if there exist constants $c,M>0,T_0>0$ such that $|f(t)|e^{-ct} \le M$ for all $t>T_0$.
Second Question:Any example which is not of exponential order but its Laplace tranform exists?If I consider $e^{t^2}$,it's not of exponential order.But does its Laplace tranform exist??
Any help is appreciated,as always.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first question, take something like
$$
f(t) = \sin(e^{t^2}).
$$
Then $f$ is bounded (so in particular of exponential growth), but 
$$
f'(t) = 2t e^{t^2} \cos( e^{t^2} )
$$
is not of exponential growth. (Look at the values for $z=2\pi k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.)

For the second question, see Jyrki's answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much mrf.

Comment: $f'(t)$ is of exponential order that can be  proved but I didn't understand why I should look for $z=2\pi k$.Please help me know this from scratch.

Answer (score 5):

Answering the second question with a "standard" example of a function that is not of exponential order, but does have a Laplace transform in the region $\Re s>0$.

Build a function out of spiky triangles
$$
\Delta_{H,A}(x)=
\begin{cases}
H-\frac{H^2}{A}|x|,&\ \text{if $|x|\le A/H$, and}\\
0,&\ \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Here $H>0,A>0$ are parameters.
You see that $\Delta_{H,A}(x)$ reaches a maximum value $H$ at $x=0$, and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Delta_{H,A}(x)\,dx=A,
$$
because the graph is a triangle of height $H$ and width $2A/H$. Furthermore, $\Delta_{H,A}(x)$ is continuous everywhere.

Because the series $\sum_n\dfrac1{n^2}$ converges, the function
$$
f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Delta_{e^{n^2},1/n^2}(x-n)
$$
will work. We have $f(n)=e^{n^2}$ for all positive integers $n$, so $f(x)$ is not of exponential order. But
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6.
$$

Consequently, by domination, the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)\,dt
$$
converges whenever $\Re s\ge0$.

Comment: Thank you.But what about the answer to my 1st question?

Comment: @kilimanjaro: see mrf's (+1) answer for that part.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This proves the wrong thing; ignore this answer.

If $f'$ is of exponential order, so is $f$. Consider the integral
$$\int_a^x f'(t) dt$$ From the fundamental theorem of calculus, this differs from $f$ by at most a constant. If $|f(x)| ≤ |g(x)|$ for sufficiently large $x$, $\int_a^x |f(t)| dt ≤ \int_a^x |g(t)| dt$ for sufficiently large $x$ and $a$. $$
|f(x)| ≤ |\int_a^x f'(t) dt| ≤ \int_a^x |f'(t)| dt ≤ \int_a^x |Me^{cx}| dt
$$ since $f(x) ≤ Me^{cx}$. 
$$\int_a^x |Me^{cx}| dt = |M| \int_a^x e^{cx} dt = |M| (\frac{e^{cx}}{c} -\frac{e^a}{c}) ≤ Ke^{cx}$$ for a constant K. Thus $f ≤ K e^{cx}$ and is by definition of exponential order.

Thus, one cannot find $f$ not of exponential so that $f'$ is of exponential order, because if $f'$ is of exponential order then $f$ must be as well, as shown above.

As for your second question, the integral defining a Laplace transform does not converge for a function not of exponential order, so it does not make sense to find a Laplace transform of such a function.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It's very informative but it still doesn't answer my question:an example (or construct it,if possible),where function is of exponential order but its derivative is not!! As for the second question:I don't agree with your very last paragraph(Please correct me ,if I am wrong).If we consider $e^{t^2}$,its Laplace transform does exist,despite the fact that $e^{t^2}$ is not of exponential order(Am I not right?Please correct me,if I am not right.).Being exponential order and piece-wise continuous is a sufficient condition and not a necessary one.Isn't it?

Comment: The answer proved that there is not a function of exponential order with a derivative is not of exponential order; if you have evidence to believe that there must be perhaps I made an error in the proof. If the Laplace transform of $e^{t^2}$ exists, I'm not sure what it could be, as the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-st + t^2} dt$ does not converge.

Comment: Laplace transform of $e^{t^2}$ is a complex function(involving a function called Dawson function).Thanks for your post.But brother,don't you think you should have posted a post containing  my answer at least?

Comment: I thought I did, but I realize now that I read your first question wrong and proved something else. Sorry.

Comment: Like I said ,it's very informative.+1,for that.

Comment: The method I used doesn't generalize to the case you're looking for, so I don't actually know the answer. I would guess that there still isn't a function that fits your requirements, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Cheers !!,I got my answer.Consider $t^{1/5}$.

Comment: @kilimanjaro Why would you think that the Laplace transform of $e^{t^2}$ exists? (It doesn't even exist in the distributional sense.)

Comment: @mrf,I checked it on wolfram alpha and I found that Laplace transform of $e^{t^2}$ is a complex function involving a function called Dawson function.

Comment: So I am confused now whether Laplace transform of $e^{t^2}$ exists or doesn't.

Comment: @kilimanjaro Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288090

Comment: @mrf,so Laplace transform of $e^{t^2}$ exists or doesn't?Actually I don't trust wolfram alpha.Most of the times it gives wrong results.